# Turn off Replace "Straight quotes" with "smart quotes" programmatically in office 2003

Tags: c#, office-interop, office-2003

Is there a way to turn off Replace "Straight quotes" with "smart quotes" in Microsoft Office 2003 programmatically? I am using `Microsoft.Office.Interop`.

**Ok, solved!
There are two options:
Application.Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes Application.Options.AutoFormatReplaceQuotes**

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what exactly is not working (exception/error message) ?

Comment: You may be out of luck, [`Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838540.aspx) would appear to be an Office 2010+ thing.

Comment: Ok, solved! There are two options:            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Options.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceQuotes
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Options.AutoFormatReplaceQuotes